# Can't Connect To Remote Database Via Putty On SQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, putty, pythonanywhere

Good evening stackoverflow.

So I have an SSH encrypted database on a server that I'm trying to connect to locally via PuTTY.

I'm trying to set up a local connection, and then load it into My SQL Workbench, but it's not being recognized.

Here's what I'm doing:

**STEP 1:** Setting Up SSH Connection in PuTTY

My screen for this looks like the following:  [image]

**STEP 2:** Setting up my SSH Tunnel via PuTTY

My screenshot for this step looks like the following:

[image]

In **Destination** I've put `myusername.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com:3306`, and then hit `ADD`

I then hit `Open` and then enter the log in credentials for my web host, NOT my database.

At this point everything checks out.

**STEP 3:** Connect to `Localhost` on port `3306` on MySQLWorkBench

At this point I load in a saved connection that sets up a connection to localhost on port 3306.  The setup screen looks like the following:

[image]

After I do this, I enter the password for my **database**, and not my webhost.

This pulls up a connection, but it is for the default MySQL connection in WorkBench, not the one from my webserver.

The screen I'm brought to is this:

[image]

These are not the tables in my PuTTY connection.  I believe they're pre-loaded into MySQL Workbench.

I've also tried these other things without success:

1. Setting up the connection port to be 3307 instead of 3306
2. Changing the hostname to `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost
3. Changing the username in the MySQL Workbench sign in to my
   database username

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I am pretty sure WorkBench does not need Putty in the middle of all this

Comment: @RiggsFolly That might be true, however I tried this angle because the instruction on how to setup a remote SSH connection via my web server was unclear, so I thought this might be more expedient given the circumstances.

Comment: Are you able to ssh into your account on PythonAnywhere with the credentials you entered into PuTTY?

Comment: @Flip yes.  I can open up a Jupyter Notebook and use the same credentials to connect to the database.  So I'm not concerned about my credentials being incorrect.

Comment: If you're running a local version of MySQL on port 3306, you will need to change the local port for the SSH tunnel to something else (you still need the remote part of the tunnel to be port 3306) and then connect MySQL workbench to that port. I believe you can do that in your second screenshot under source port.